# Getting the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance" with core data and swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, selector

So, I have been working on this problem for a couple of days now. I have code that preloads data from a text file, parses it, and then converts it to an array of `TestPreload` Objects. These objects then go through my `preload` function and get stored into `Test` entities. This is my code for the `Test.swift`:

```
class Test: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: Int;
    @NSManaged var name: String;
    @NSManaged var wTimeBreaks: Int;
    @NSManaged var wTimeSections: Int;
}
```

This is my code that parses my preload data:

```
let TestURL: NSURL;
let SectionURL: NSURL;
let Encoding: NSStringEncoding;
let Error: NSErrorPointer;
let delimiter = ",";

func parseTest()->[TestPreload] {
        var items:[TestPreload] = [];

        if let content = String(contentsOfURL: TestURL, encoding: Encoding, error: Error) {
            let lines: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) as [String];

            for line in lines {
                var values: [String] = [];

                if(line != "") {
                    values = line.componentsSeparatedByString(delimiter);

                    let item = TestPreload(ID: values[0].toInt()!, Name: values[1], waitTimeBreaks: values[2].toInt()!, waitTimeSections: values[3].toInt()!);
                    items.append(item);
                }
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

This is my `TestPreload.swift`:

```
class TestPreload {
    var id: Int;
    var name: String;
    var wTimeBreaks: Int;
    var wTimeSections: Int;

    init(ID: Int, Name: String, waitTimeBreaks: Int, waitTimeSections: Int) {
        id = ID;
        name = Name;
        wTimeBreaks = waitTimeBreaks;
        wTimeSections = waitTimeSections;
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the preload function (where the data gets stored into CoreData), which is in my `AppDelegate.swift` file:

func preloadData() {
        let contentsOfTests = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("testPreload", withExtension: "csv");
        let contentsOfSection = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("sectionPreload", withExtension: "csv");

```
    var error: NSError?;
    let Parser = CSVParse(tPreload: contentsOfTests!, sPreload: contentsOfSection!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error);
    let testData = Parser.parseTest();
    let sectionData = Parser.parseSection();

    if let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext {
        for test in testData {
            let currentTest = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Test", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Test;

            currentTest.id = test.id;
            currentTest.name = test.name;
            currentTest.wTimeBreaks = test.wTimeBreaks;
            currentTest.wTimeSections = test.wTimeSections;

            if(managedObjectContext.save(&error) != true) {
                println("insert error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
            }
        }

        for section in sectionData {
            let currentSection = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Section", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Section;

            currentSection.is_break = section.is_break;
            currentSection.is_editable = section.is_editable;
            currentSection.name = section.name;
            currentSection.sectionNumber = section.sectionNumber;
            currentSection.testID = section.testID;
            currentSection.time = section.time;

            if(managedObjectContext.save(&error) != true) {
                println("insert error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked in other places, and they all suggest that the problem is that my object isn't actually referencing a project. The weird part is that some of my statements work, such as `currentSection.is_break = section.is_break;`, however it throws and error when it reaches `currentSection.sectionNumber = section.sectionNumber;` This is the error that I get:

```
2015-06-11 13:03:16.631 satTimer[53733:3620372] -[satTimer.Section setSectionNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9a81f543c0
2015-06-11 13:03:16.635 satTimer[53733:3620372] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[satTimer.Section setSectionNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9a81f543c0'
```

I'm really ripping my hair out on this one, so any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
These are my entities, `Test` and `Section` from my xcdatamodeld file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-p9YZvcrWdHVmdkbHJldWFDUU0/view?usp=sharing

This is my code for `Section.swift`:

```
class Section: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var is_break: Bool;
    @NSManaged var is_editable: Bool;
    @NSManaged var name: String;
    @NSManaged var sectionNumber: NSNumber;
    @NSManaged var testID: NSNumber;
    @NSManaged var time: NSNumber;
}
```

Once again, I can't thank you enough for just looking at this!

Comment: `currentSection` is certainly a `Section` - otherwise the `as!` would fail. Can you show your xcdatamodel file? Does it actually have a `sectionNumber` property? What does `Section.swift` look like?

Comment: @AaronBrager, I just looked over and it looks like I tried to cut some corners with the naming of my variables. Even though this was a really dumb mistake on my part, I just wanted to thank you for taking the time to review this. Cheers!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out there was an inconsistancy between my `xcdatamodeld` file and my objects. Thanks to everyone who spent time on this problem.

Cheers!

Comment: I was getting a similar error, and your answer made me double-check it. Same issue LOL

Comment: Helped to fix my problem too :)

Comment: You made my day... also double-checked the structure and the problem was gone!

Comment: Same issue still happening 5 years later... and this answer helped :D

Comment: what does this mean? what was inconsistent?

Comment: Cleaning build folder and then rebuild fixed the issue for me.